# Looking to download SubSonic version 2.0.3 exe file

Tags: subsonic

I am working on a project which was created in 2005 using SubSonic version 2.0.3. I created some stored procedures in a database.  I have tried downloading SubSonic version 2.1 but the functionality in the code is not doing what it is expected to do.  I am running out of time and I will not be able to rewrite the code.  Can you tell me where can i download Subsonic version 2.0.3 exe file?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic 2.0.3 is available on codeplex:

http://subsonictools.codeplex.com/releases/view/5647

Other than the installer, you may also download the source and build it yourself.